# What does c^n in vim do?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I went to open a browser window today with CTRL+n and I wasn't in the browser I was in vim, when a menu popped up with what looked to be about every word in my entire document.

What does CTRL+n do, and where can I find the documentation for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal mode, it basically moves your cursor down, it is like pressing `RETURN`. From `:help CTRL-n`:

```
<NL> or CTRL-N                      [count] lines downward linewise.
```

In insert mode, it triggers the autocompletion (`n` for "Next" matching term). From `help i_CTRL-n`:

```
CTRL-N                  Find next match for words that start with the                                                                                                                                              
                        keyword in front of the cursor, looking in places                                                                                                                                          
                        specified with the 'complete' option.  The found                                                                                                                                           
                        keyword is inserted in front of the cursor.
```

In insert mode, `CTRL-p` finds the previous match.